# The SQLite provider of Entity Framework sometimes does not perform the insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The command should be executed in a specific order, not as a query. I checked the log when the `InitializeAccount` method was running. The `dbContext` only inserted 2 `TaskTypeModel`. I expected the order of the queries to be the same as the order stated in the method.

However, in the log, I noticed that the `dbContext` inserted `Users` in the last position instead. It should have been in the second position. What could possibly be causing this? because no error. it skips 1 insert query also. I try net 7 and 6. same result.

```
@page "/installation"
@inject ApplicationDbContext dbContext

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Initialize">Initialize</MudButton>

@code {

    void Initialize()
    {
        var facebook = dbContext.Sites.Add(new SiteModel
        { 
            Name="Facebook", 
            Url="https://www.facebook.com" 
        });

        dbContext.TaskTypes.AddRange(new List<TaskTypeModel>() 
        { 
            new(){ Name="GroupPost", Site=facebook.Entity },
            new(){ Name="PagesssPost", Site=facebook.Entity },
            new(){ Name="ScrapeGroupMembers", Site=facebook.Entity }
        });

        var entries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries();    

        foreach(var entry in entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Result tracker entries

> Project.Models.SiteModel
>
> Project.Models.TaskTypeModel
>
> Project.Models.TaskTypeModel

SiteModel.cs

```
public class SiteModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Invalid url format")]
    public string Url { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

TaskTypeModel.cs

```
public class TaskTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public SiteModel Site { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
builder.Entity<TaskTypeModel>().ToTable("TaskTypes");
builder.Entity<TaskTypeModel>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Site)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<TaskTypeModel>(t => t.SiteId);
builder.Entity<TaskTypeModel>()
    .HasIndex(t => t.SiteId)
    .IsUnique(false);
```

Comment: If the data aren't related (as is the case here) then the order of inserts doesn't matter and EF determines it itself, probably based on order on which the types are registered in the model. Either way, it doesn't matter. That leaves only one issue: 3 `TaskType` object should be inserted. The code doesn't give any clue why only two are inserted. Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Which two of the three `TaskType` objects are inserted?  What is the definition of the TaskType model class and table definition in SQLite?

Comment: @PaulPearce it inserts 1st and 3rd only. I check use mysqlclient. the data insert 2 only.

Comment: @GertArnold im sure only 2 insert. i check the data with mysql client. i see also console in development mode. it also 2 query only. I cant debug if no message tell me whats wrong. example. database locking or something. it just run fine. i try delete and do again.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time that the wrong database is checked to see if inserted data is actually there (I know, because I did it myself, not even once). There's really no reason why EF would insert 2 records. If there's an error, none would be inserted. Without error, three.

Comment: SQLite and MySQL are two different DBMS. What exactly are you using? Be specific.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov by the way, i try to switch to MySQL provider. it also same result.

Comment: @GertArnold I switch to MySQL provider also same result. I move now to raw query.

Comment: It must be something not related to the code you show. There's no reason why EF would skip one of three identical (for EF) records added to the context.

Comment: @GertArnold I try to debug to look up entries of tracker. it shows me 2 query with TaskType. I updated code that cause problem and include relationship.

Comment: All your code changes still don't show any likely cause why EF would single-handedly decide to just discard one object from a collection you add to the context. I'm sorry, but if we can't reproduce the issue, we can't answer it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I looked at your new edit, so I post my **tested & working** solution:

```
void Initialize()
{
    SiteModel facebook = new SiteModel
    {
        Name = "Facebook",
        Url = "https://www.facebook.com"
    };
    dbContext.Sites.Add(facebook);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    int fbId = facebook.Id;

    dbContext.TaskTypes.AddRange(new List<TaskTypeModel>()
    {
        new(){ Name="GroupPost", SiteId = fbId },
        new(){ Name="PagesssPost", SiteId = fbId },
        new(){ Name="ScrapeGroupMembers", SiteId = fbId }
    });
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //now there are 4 entries in the ChangeTracker
    var entries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries();
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Entity);
    }
}
```

In the OnModelCreating, I think You don't need to specify **SiteId** index column to be not unique, because it's already a non unique foreign key (more TaskTypes can have the same Site).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 
    builder.Entity<TaskTypeModel>().ToTable("TaskTypes");
    builder.Entity<TaskTypeModel>()
        .HasOne(t => t.Site)
        .WithMany(t => t.TaskTypes)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.SiteId);                
}

public class SiteModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Invalid url format")]
    public string Url { get; set; } = null!;
    public IList<TaskTypeModel> TaskTypes { get; set; }
}

public class TaskTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public SiteModel Site { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

P.S. @Gert Arnold: the next time, post your own solution, if You have one, not always being there to judge if others make mistakes. Ok? Enjoy.

Comment: I need an explanation as to why this weird thing is happening. I mean, assigning a value with navigation can result in this strange behavior, which seems inconsistent. Tutorial in official site show code that assign directly with navigation. But, the result is incosistent. Should i avoid navigation assign, never use it?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how your code works exactly. Based on my findings, it seems that the relationship needs to be defined explicitly on both sides, even if one side is not being used. It's strange to retrieve the task type from the site in this case.

Comment: Can you modify your code to only include the second part? There doesn't seem to be any issue with passing it to navigation.

Comment: You must use navigation assign to the child objects. I will explain: **1.** In your code, You are using a one-to-many relationship: one Site has many TaskTypes (typically a Collection), so in your Site class, You should indicate a **navigation property** as Collection (I used IList interface). **2.** So, You have a parent class instance **facebook** which is the first entity that You must add to the database "Sites" table. Saving it will return its Id, which You can use as foreign key to store its child entities.

Comment: Alternatively to the SiteId, You can use the parent object facebook also, but You must use the fullfilled parent class read from its database table after You saved it.  **3.** In the OnCreatingModel there was some mistake because You probably wrote it in a hurry... good luck.

Comment: Can you please remove the second answer that appears during the addition process? This will allow me to accept your answer without causing confusion for others. I believe I only need to describe the navigation on one side, as I am certain I will not access the tasktype from the site model. However, the entity framework requires explicit definition of navigation on both sides.

Comment: I don't judge "others", I judge *answers*. I clearly said that the code in the question doesn't give any reason to think why it should fail. I'm 100% sure we can't reproduce the issue based on the code in the question. So what is there to answer?

Comment: My "P.S." was for your comment on my first answer that David asked to me to remove... so your comment has deleted also... no problem... it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, it matters to me. If I only post factual comments (*No, this can't be the cause of the issue. "You should not put a reference to an existing parent class" isn't even true. It's perfectly fine to set the reference.*) I don't like to be accused of judging others, which is still the last line of your answer.

Comment: I don't wrote "judging others", but, anyway, I said that badly: my intention was to say "...being there to show if the others make mistakes"...